# The usage of TaskExecutor in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

Client application have a lot of request to server. However, i need to also keep my thread in server.
For example, client sends a request to server then server reply to client and again same client will send a request to server. For that, thread should continue from where it left off. Also, when another client send request, thread should be newly executed. I tried runnable class object is null, then start thread otherwise keep using same thread. I would like to find better solution. Can i use taskexecutor for that and if it is possible how can i do that in spring? Can you help me please?

Comment: TaskExecutor usually starts a new Thread. Maybe the bean scope "session" is what you're looking for. Each bean definition gets a new instance for a new session:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes

Comment: @The Frozen One How execute thread again when new request? When i send request to server, server returns response and again same client will send request and thread should be continue to work from same place. How can i recognize if the solution is scope? Because client-server, server-client and client-server again and continues to work from same way but another client creates new request and thread should start new

Comment: The scope "session" means, that each (http) session creation will receive an new bean instance. Its life cycle is until the session ends. So it's possible to have a stateful object for each user session. Maybe this is not the solution you need, but if not, you have to provide more details, e.g. already written code which doesn't work. Is your client the browser or do you have a custom client?

Comment: @ The Frozen One client is desktop application